# Unable to add properly child node in given xml file, libxml2

Tags: c++, c, xml, unix, libxml2

What I am doing is reading a **xml** file and trying to add a child node to  a given **xml** file. But the problem is, it is not showing properly in the file here is the code:

```
xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr nodeptr=NULL , node = NULL , node_child =NULL;
doc = xmlParseFile("Mainfile.xml");
if (doc == NULL ) {
fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
return;
}
nodeptr = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
if (nodeptr == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
xmlFreeDoc(doc); 
return;
}
if (xmlStrcmp(nodeptr->name, (const xmlChar *) "story")) {
fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
return;
}

node = xmlNewNode( NULL, BAD_CAST "Account" );
xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "id", BAD_CAST "A001");
xmlAddChild(nodeptr , node);

node_child = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST "Country",BAD_CAST "US");
xmlAddChild(node,node_child);
xmlAddChild(nodeptr , node);


node_child = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST "City", BAD_CAST "ABC");
xmlAddChild(node,node_child);
xmlAddChild(nodeptr , node);

node_child = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST "ZIP",BAD_CAST "34040");
xmlAddChild(node,node_child);
xmlAddChild(nodeptr , node);

xmlSaveFile("Mainfile.xml", doc);
xmlFree(doc);
```

And the structure of given xml file is

```
< ?xml version="1.0"? >  
< Project >  
       < author >John Fleck< /author >  
       < datewritten >June 2, 2002< /datewritten >  
       < keyword >example keyword< /keyword >  
       < Account id = "A000" >  
           < Country >UK< /Country >  
           < City >XYZ< /City >  
           < Zip >67688< /Zip >  
       < /Account >  
< /Project >
```

and after using my code the xml showing the content in below format

```
< ?xml version="1.0"? >   
< Project >  
       < author >John Fleck< /author >  
       < datewritten >June 2, 2002</datewritten>  
       < keyword >example keyword< /keyword >    
       < Account id = "A000" >   
           < Country >UK< /Country >    
           < City >XYZ< /City >    
           < Zip >67688< /Zip >    
        < /Account >  
        < Account id = "A001" >< Country >US< /Country >< City >ABC< /City >< Zip >34040< /Zip >< /Account >< /Project >
```

The main problem is it is not adding the child node with proper indentation.

Can anyone suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your XML output didn't come through, but to get proper indentation, try using [`xmlSaveFormatFile`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSaveFormatFile) and use 1 for the `format`.  Also call `xmlKeepBlanksDefault(0)` before your whole XML stuff and I believe it should give the indentation you want (without actually being able to see what you're looking for).